# Converting image to text for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing apps for wp7 and am new to these things. I want **convert an image to text** like selecting an  existing image or capture a new image and if there is a text present in that image, it should show those text on a **TextBox**. Can anybody help me with this,please? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What you are talking about is a SERIOUS amount of coding. To give you an idea. Most software companies if not all just license it. 

If you are really hell bent on it look into changing your image to a bit array then you can search the bits for patterns that match bit arrays of letters. 

Good luck chief.

Comment: @AMR Thank you for your reply sir...I just want to learn about these things, if you have any samples, please provide me!

Comment: I hate to be the rain cloud but I have ZERO examples on this. I have been trying to crack this nut for about a year and a half but there is practically no code out there demonstrating it and even less on theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to spend years on developing your own solution, you could try these:

http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/default.aspx

BTW the search term for what you're looking for is "Optical Character Recognition" or "OCR".

Comment: Be aware Project Hawaii is for academic use only, and can't be used in an app submitted to the Marketplace.